User Logged In Issue: iisexpress.exe has exited with Code -1 (0xffffffff)
I'm facing an issue while working on an ASP.NET Core application with Identity. After logging in successfully, I noticed that the application exits unexpectedly with the following log:

_1101113.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.LoginModel: Information: User logged in.
The program '[8984] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).

I have tried the following steps to resolve the issue:

Restarting the IIS Express server

Checking the application configuration settings in launchSettings.json

Ensuring that my environment variables are correctly set


However, the problem still persists. Can anyone help me understand the cause of this issue and suggest a possible solution?

Could be an unhandled exception, or a problem with your installation. Have you tried debugging your application outside of IIS Express? Use the drop-down next to the run button to switch from "IIS Express" to "your application name", which will launch it directly.

Does it crush right after login prosess? You probably have some redirections after login, so try to strip off as much as you can (like redirections, cookies saving, db calls). You may also try to set in code that you already are logged in and redirect to whatever location you need (may be you have problem in login prosessing code). And try to add logs to each method start and end, so then you can see inside which method it breaks.

if you are getting this error right after logging the user, could you please share your authentication code. could you enable detailed logging: "Logging": {     "LogLevel": {         "Default": "Debug",         "Microsoft": "Information",         "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"     } } have you checked event viewer logs? Which .net version are you using?
